# Python making scoreboard based on list input

Tags: python, list, class, append

I am trying to make a scoreboard based on an input which has a list of all rounds played and their result. I have already split this input so that each round of games is one list; in it, one item is one game played. Each game is noted as 'White Black ResultWhite ResultBlack'.

For example, with three rounds and six players, it is as follows. The first list is the players, followed by the rounds (2-4). 1 = win, 0.5 = tie, 0 = loss.

```
[['Erik', 'Daniel', 'Charlotte', 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Femke'], ['Anna Femke 1 0', 'Bob Erik 0 1', 'Charlotte Daniel 0.5 0.5'], ['Erik Anna 1 0', 'Femke Charlotte 0.5 0.5', 'Daniel Bob 1 0'], ['Daniel Erik 0.5 0.5', 'Charlotte Anna 1 0', 'Bob Femke 1 0']]
```

Now, I want to:

- Identify the first list as *names* in a class called player_result
- Ignore the first list of *names* from this point onwards
- Split the list of all rounds into individual lists
- Add ResultWhite (index 2) to the *points* in said class of White (index 0) and vice verse for ResultBlack and Black

I have managed to reach the first three points with the code below, but I cannot resolve the last remark. I have looked into append but I cannot figure it out. If anyone can help it would be great!

```
class player_result:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

def determine_output(input):
    splits = input.split("\n\n")
    rounds = [i.split('\n') for i in splits]
    print(rounds)
    playernames = rounds[0]
    players = []
    for name in playernames:
        players.append(player_result(name))
    print('Player:', players[0].name)
    amount_rounds = len(rounds) - 1
    print('Rounds:', amount_rounds)
    for i in range(len(rounds) - 1):
        print('Round',i + 1,rounds[i + 1])
```

Edit: some more clarification on the end result. My idea is that the list is being registered as [White Black ResultWhite ResultBlack], and the output below is being presented by all White and Black being player, with the total of their points received. The output / result that I am after would look like the following. This would be achieved by the name being the *names* item of class player_result, and the score being a new *points* item of class player_result.

```
Erik: 2.5
Daniel: 2
Charlotte: 2
Anna: 1
Bob: 1
Femke: 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. Have you tried running it? Does it output what you want to see?

Comment: Hi @quamrana, it does what I expect. I am unsure how to present it nicely, but the output is as follows:

`Player: Erik # Note: this is just to check if my connection with class player_result works.<br/>
Rounds: 3<br/>
Round 1 ['Anna Femke 1 0', 'Bob Erik 0 1', 'Charlotte Daniel 0.5 0.5']<br/>
Round 2 ['Erik Anna 1 0', 'Femke Charlotte 0.5 0.5', 'Daniel Bob 1 0']<br/>
Round 3 ['Daniel Erik 0.5 0.5', 'Charlotte Anna 1 0', 'Bob Femke 1 0']`
This is as I expected, now it is a matter of knowing how to split by space and indexing them without the rounds 'starting to overlap each other'.

Comment: I don't get this. I get an error at: `players.append(player_result(name))`.

Comment: @quamrana apologies! I have not posted the full code, only the part of it concerning my question. I've edited my post to include the full code.

Comment: Ok, I can run your code now. So `"This is as I expected"`. But, I presume, you now want something different. Can you edit your question to include the real output you are after?

Comment: @quamrana I've edited the post; thanks already for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step you are missing is to make a `dict` keyed on the players name. This will allow you to look up each player to accrue their scores. Also I have added a `score` attribute to `player_result`.

Also note that I have kept your original list that you posted rather than the text that your function `determine_output()` currently expects.

```py
class player_result:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

def determine_output(rounds):
    #splits = input.split("\n\n")
    #rounds = [i.split('\n') for i in splits]
    print(rounds)

    players = {}
    for name in rounds[0]:
        players[name] = player_result(name)

    amount_rounds = len(rounds) - 1
    print('Rounds:', amount_rounds)

    for one_round in rounds[1:]:
        for game in one_round:
            white,black,result_white, result_black = game.split()
            players[white].score += float(result_white)
            players[black].score += float(result_black)
    for player in players.values():
        print(f'{player.name}: {player.score}')

rounds = [['Erik', 'Daniel', 'Charlotte', 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Femke'], ['Anna Femke 1 0', 'Bob Erik 0 1', 'Charlotte Daniel 0.5 0.5'], ['Erik Anna 1 0', 'Femke Charlotte 0.5 0.5', 'Daniel Bob 1 0'], ['Daniel Erik 0.5 0.5', 'Charlotte Anna 1 0', 'Bob Femke 1 0']]

determine_output(rounds)
```

Output as requested.

Comment: Tried running it and works perfectly; question marked as answered. Thanks so much, I'll look more into dict for further problems!